# Grab first directory of URL with php array or search/replace

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, friendly-url

I a URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.site.com/subdomain1/product/123123/variable-text-goes-here
```

I'm trying to extract the first directory in the URL, or `/subdomain1/`

I don't really care how I get it, either through a wildcard replace or by breaking apart the URL into an array. Unfortunately, I'm not having much luck either way.

Some important points:
a) `/product/` will always be the same exact text "product"
b) the number and variable-text parts of the url (last 2 bits) are totally variable.
c) The subdomain1 part is also variable

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$test1 = explode('/', $kevtest, 1);
echo 'This is the directory - '.$test1;
 ?>
```

The results on the page look like this:

```
This is the directory - Array
```

I'm not so familiar with Arrays, so I'm not having any luck pulling out the results of the array.

Alternatively, it would be just fine to search/replace out the rest of the variable URL to get me the first part of the URL.

```
$test1 = str_replace("/product/ (how to I wildcard here?)","",$r);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/subdomain1/product/123123/variable-text-goes-here';
$path = parse_url($url)['path'];
echo explode('/', $path)[1];
```

If your PHP is < 5.4, use this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/subdomain1/product/123123/variable-text-goes-here';
$urlParts = parse_url($url);
$path = $urlParts['path'];
$subdomain = explode('/', $path);
echo $subdomain[1];
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in...it's happening here:  $path = parse_url($url)['path'];

Comment: Thanks @Matthew.  So, I'm going to have to remember to change this when our PHP upgrades?  We are on 5.3.x right now.

Comment: @Kevin, no, you don't need to change the code when you'll upgrade to 5.4, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays work where you have a key and a value

```
$var = array('val1', 'val2');
var_dump($var);
```

Dumps out

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "val1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "val2"
}
```

`0` and `1` are the keys here And you reference them by `$var[0]`, etc. Now, [explode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) works by breaking your string up by the delimiter and returning an array. You can see the contents by using [var_dump](http://us.php.net/function.var-dump)

```
$var = explode('/', '/subdomain1/product/123123/variable-text-goes-here');
var_dump($var);
```

Dumps out

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(10) "subdomain1"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "product"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "123123"
  [4]=>
  string(23) "variable-text-goes-here"
}
```

So... in this case you want to reference

```
$var[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation of the the arrays  +1 for that, but I marked the first answer as correct since it was first.  But the first answer depended on which php version I was running.  Is this true for your answer as well?

Comment: Nothing in my answer is version dependent. In 5.4 and later you can both execute and reference the return (if it's an array) in one fell swoop (it's called dereferencing). That's why it didn't work for you. Glad you got your answer tho

Answer (score 0):

TESTED:

```
<?php
   $r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
   $test1 = explode('/', $r);
   echo $test1[3]."Array position #3<br />"; 
?>
```